# Changing airlines at JFK (enroute to Moscow)

Tags: transit, jfk, moscow, aeroflot

My daughter will be flying from Atlanta to JFK via Delta. Then from JFK to Moscow via Aeroflot. Will she have to go through security checkpoints again when she switches over from domestic to international at JFK? Will the bags be automatically transferred?

Answer (score 10):

The good news first - Delta do "interline" bags with Aeroflot, so she will be able to check the bags all the way through to Moscow.  If the two flights are booked on the one ticket this should happen automatically.  If they are on different tickets, then you will need to show a printout of the e-ticket when checking in with Delta.  Either way, be sure to check that the luggage tags have "SVO" listed on them, which is the code for Moscow.

Now the bad news - Aeroflot operates out of Terminal 1 at JFK.  Delta operates out of terminal s 2 and 3 (and from May, terminal 4).  There is no air-side connection between terminals 1 and 2/3/4, so she will need to exit security and either walk to terminal 1, or catch the free "Airtran" between terminals and then re-clear security in terminal 1.

If she's also doing the return trip the story will be the same, except that she WILL need to collect her bags at JFK and re-check them.  This is required due to US customs, and occurs regardless of whether Aeroflot tag the bags all the way through to Atlanta or not.

Comment: Not DME but SVO

Comment: Thank you Doc! Just the answers I needed. Do you think 2.5 hours is enough time between flights?

Comment: 2.5 hours is plenty of time, unless the inbound flight is significantly delayed which is unlikely.

Comment: *either walk to terminal 1* - Yikes!  That's currently one ugly walk.

Comment: Walking between T1 and T2/3 is probably about 300 meters further than catching the air train (Plus the distance to the gate, but that's the same for both walking/airtrain).  The AirTrain only runs every 7 minutes, so the time taken for both will be, on average, about the same.

Comment: @Doc It's not that far.  Just not comfortable.

Comment: @Karlson: What's so uncomfortable about it?

Answer (score 6):

There is good news and not so good news.

The good news is that because Delta and Aeroflot codeshare your daughters bags will be checked in directly to the destination.

The not so good news is that [Aeroflot is located in Terminal 1](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airlines.html) and [Delta flight will likely to arrive to Terminal 3](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airlines.html).  Delta does have a shuttle running [between the terminals it operates in](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/airports-and-aircraft/airports/new-york-jfk.html) but it doesn't appear that it runs that shuttle to Terminal 1.  So it is quite likely to necessitate going through security.